# how to get text inbetween XML tags

Tags: xml, text, get, tags

i have this XML code

```
    <Item>
      <modelName>btype</modelName>
      <txdName>btype</txdName>
      <handlingId>C0met</handlingId>
      <gameName>ROOSEVELT</gameName>
      <vehicleMakeName>ALBANY</vehicleMakeName>
      <expressionDictName>null</expressionDictName>
      <expressionName>null</expressionName>
      <animConvRoofDictName>null</animConvRoofDictName>
      <animConvRoofName>null</animConvRoofName>
      <animConvRoofWindowsAffected />
      <ptfxAssetName>veh_car</ptfxAssetName>
      <audioNameHash />
      <layout>LAYOUT_VAN_ROOSEVELT</layout>
      <coverBoundOffsets>ROOSEVELT_COVER_OFFSET_INFO</coverBoundOffsets>
      <explosionInfo>EXPLOSION_INFO_DEFAULT</explosionInfo>
      <scenarioLayout />
      <cameraName>DEFAULT_FOLLOW_VEHICLE_CAMERA</cameraName>
      <aimCameraName>DEFAULT_THIRD_PERSON_VEHICLE_AIM_CAMERA</aimCameraName>
      <bonnetCameraName>VEHICLE_BONNET_CAMERA_STANDARD_LONG_EXTRA_LOW</bonnetCameraName>
      <vfxInfoName>VFXVEHICLEINFO_CAR_GENERIC</vfxInfoName>
      <shouldUseCinematicViewMode value="true" />
      <shouldCameraTransitionOnClimbUpDown value="false" />
      <shouldCameraIgnoreExiting value="false" />
      <AllowPretendOccupants value="true" />
      <AllowJoyriding value="true" />
      <AllowSundayDriving value="true" />
      <AllowBodyColorMapping value="true" />
      <wheelScale value="0.245000" />
      <wheelScaleRear value="0.450700" />
      <dirtLevelMin value="0.000000" />
      <dirtLevelMax value="0.800000" />
      <envEffScaleMin value="0.000000" />
      <envEffScaleMax value="1.000000" />
      <envEffScaleMin2 value="0.000000" />
      <envEffScaleMax2 value="1.000000" />
      <damageMapScale value="0.500000" />
      <damageOffsetScale value="0.500000" />
      <diffuseTint value="0x00FFFFFF" />
      <steerWheelMult value="1.000000" />
      <HDTextureDist value="5.000000" />
      <lodDistances content="float_array">10
 25
 70
 500
</lodDistances>
      <identicalModelSpawnDistance value="20" />
      <maxNumOfSameColor value="10" />
      <defaultBodyHealth value="1000.000000" />
      <pretendOccupantsScale value="1.000000" />
      <visibleSpawnDistScale value="1.000000" />
      <trackerPathWidth value="2.000000" />
      <weaponForceMult value="1.000000" />
      <frequency value="1" />
      <swankness>SWANKNESS_5</swankness>
      <maxNum value="2" />
      <flags>FLAG_SPORTS FLAG_RICH_CAR FLAG_COUNT_AS_FACEBOOK_DRIVEN FLAG_EXTRAS_ALL FLAG_EXTRAS_STRONG</flags>
      <type>VEHICLE_TYPE_CAR</type>
      <plateType>VPT_BACK_PLATES</plateType>
      <vehicleClass>VC_SPORT_CLASSIC</vehicleClass>
      <wheelType>VWT_LOWRIDER</wheelType>
      <trailers />
      <additionalTrailers />
      <drivers />
      <extraIncludes />
      <doorsWithCollisionWhenClosed />
      <driveableDoors />
      <bumpersNeedToCollideWithMap value="false" />
      <needsRopeTexture value="false" />
      <requiredExtras />
      <rewards />
      <cinematicPartCamera>
        <Item>WHEEL_FRONT_RIGHT_CAMERA</Item>
        <Item>WHEEL_FRONT_LEFT_CAMERA</Item>
        <Item>WHEEL_REAR_RIGHT_CAMERA</Item>
        <Item>WHEEL_REAR_LEFT_CAMERA</Item>
      </cinematicPartCamera>
      <NmBraceOverrideSet />
      <buoyancySphereOffset x="0.000000" y="0.000000" z="0.000000" />
      <buoyancySphereSizeScale value="1.000000" />
      <pOverrideRagdollThreshold type="NULL" />
    </Item>
```

i need to get the text between the first Item tags

i tried using this

```
string s = "<Item>
      <modelName>btype</modelName>
      <txdName>btype</txdName>
      <handlingId>C0met</handlingId>
      <gameName>ROOSEVELT</gameName>
      <vehicleMakeName>ALBANY</vehicleMakeName>
      <expressionDictName>null</expressionDictName>
      <expressionName>null</expressionName>
      <animConvRoofDictName>null</animConvRoofDictName>
      <animConvRoofName>null</animConvRoofName>
      <animConvRoofWindowsAffected />
      <ptfxAssetName>veh_car</ptfxAssetName>
      <audioNameHash />
      <layout>LAYOUT_VAN_ROOSEVELT</layout>
      <coverBoundOffsets>ROOSEVELT_COVER_OFFSET_INFO</coverBoundOffsets>
      <explosionInfo>EXPLOSION_INFO_DEFAULT</explosionInfo>
      <scenarioLayout />
      <cameraName>DEFAULT_FOLLOW_VEHICLE_CAMERA</cameraName>
      <aimCameraName>DEFAULT_THIRD_PERSON_VEHICLE_AIM_CAMERA</aimCameraName>
      <bonnetCameraName>VEHICLE_BONNET_CAMERA_STANDARD_LONG_EXTRA_LOW</bonnetCameraName>
      <vfxInfoName>VFXVEHICLEINFO_CAR_GENERIC</vfxInfoName>
      <shouldUseCinematicViewMode value="true" />
      <shouldCameraTransitionOnClimbUpDown value="false" />
      <shouldCameraIgnoreExiting value="false" />
      <AllowPretendOccupants value="true" />
      <AllowJoyriding value="true" />
      <AllowSundayDriving value="true" />
      <AllowBodyColorMapping value="true" />
      <wheelScale value="0.245000" />
      <wheelScaleRear value="0.450700" />
      <dirtLevelMin value="0.000000" />
      <dirtLevelMax value="0.800000" />
      <envEffScaleMin value="0.000000" />
      <envEffScaleMax value="1.000000" />
      <envEffScaleMin2 value="0.000000" />
      <envEffScaleMax2 value="1.000000" />
      <damageMapScale value="0.500000" />
      <damageOffsetScale value="0.500000" />
      <diffuseTint value="0x00FFFFFF" />
      <steerWheelMult value="1.000000" />
      <HDTextureDist value="5.000000" />
      <lodDistances content="float_array">10
 25
 70
 500
</lodDistances>
      <identicalModelSpawnDistance value="20" />
      <maxNumOfSameColor value="10" />
      <defaultBodyHealth value="1000.000000" />
      <pretendOccupantsScale value="1.000000" />
      <visibleSpawnDistScale value="1.000000" />
      <trackerPathWidth value="2.000000" />
      <weaponForceMult value="1.000000" />
      <frequency value="1" />
      <swankness>SWANKNESS_5</swankness>
      <maxNum value="2" />
      <flags>FLAG_SPORTS FLAG_RICH_CAR FLAG_COUNT_AS_FACEBOOK_DRIVEN FLAG_EXTRAS_ALL FLAG_EXTRAS_STRONG</flags>
      <type>VEHICLE_TYPE_CAR</type>
      <plateType>VPT_BACK_PLATES</plateType>
      <vehicleClass>VC_SPORT_CLASSIC</vehicleClass>
      <wheelType>VWT_LOWRIDER</wheelType>
      <trailers />
      <additionalTrailers />
      <drivers />
      <extraIncludes />
      <doorsWithCollisionWhenClosed />
      <driveableDoors />
      <bumpersNeedToCollideWithMap value="false" />
      <needsRopeTexture value="false" />
      <requiredExtras />
      <rewards />
      <cinematicPartCamera>
        <Item>WHEEL_FRONT_RIGHT_CAMERA</Item>
        <Item>WHEEL_FRONT_LEFT_CAMERA</Item>
        <Item>WHEEL_REAR_RIGHT_CAMERA</Item>
        <Item>WHEEL_REAR_LEFT_CAMERA</Item>
      </cinematicPartCamera>
      <NmBraceOverrideSet />
      <buoyancySphereOffset x="0.000000" y="0.000000" z="0.000000" />
      <buoyancySphereSizeScale value="1.000000" />
      <pOverrideRagdollThreshold type="NULL" />
    </Item>";
Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(s.IndexOf("<Item>") + "<Item>".Length, s.IndexOf("</Item>") - s.IndexOf("<Item>") - "<Item>".Length));
```

but it give me this

```
    <modelName>btype</modelName>
      <txdName>btype</txdName>
      <handlingId>C0met</handlingId>
      <gameName>ROOSEVELT</gameName>
      <vehicleMakeName>ALBANY</vehicleMakeName>
      <expressionDictName>null</expressionDictName>
      <expressionName>null</expressionName>
      <animConvRoofDictName>null</animConvRoofDictName>
      <animConvRoofName>null</animConvRoofName>
      <animConvRoofWindowsAffected />
      <ptfxAssetName>veh_car</ptfxAssetName>
      <audioNameHash />
      <layout>LAYOUT_VAN_ROOSEVELT</layout>
      <coverBoundOffsets>ROOSEVELT_COVER_OFFSET_INFO</coverBoundOffsets>
      <explosionInfo>EXPLOSION_INFO_DEFAULT</explosionInfo>
      <scenarioLayout />
      <cameraName>DEFAULT_FOLLOW_VEHICLE_CAMERA</cameraName>
      <aimCameraName>DEFAULT_THIRD_PERSON_VEHICLE_AIM_CAMERA</aimCameraName>
      <bonnetCameraName>VEHICLE_BONNET_CAMERA_STANDARD_LONG_EXTRA_LOW</bonnetCameraName>
      <vfxInfoName>VFXVEHICLEINFO_CAR_GENERIC</vfxInfoName>
      <shouldUseCinematicViewMode value="true" />
      <shouldCameraTransitionOnClimbUpDown value="false" />
      <shouldCameraIgnoreExiting value="false" />
      <AllowPretendOccupants value="true" />
      <AllowJoyriding value="true" />
      <AllowSundayDriving value="true" />
      <AllowBodyColorMapping value="true" />
      <wheelScale value="0.245000" />
      <wheelScaleRear value="0.450700" />
      <dirtLevelMin value="0.000000" />
      <dirtLevelMax value="0.800000" />
      <envEffScaleMin value="0.000000" />
      <envEffScaleMax value="1.000000" />
      <envEffScaleMin2 value="0.000000" />
      <envEffScaleMax2 value="1.000000" />
      <damageMapScale value="0.500000" />
      <damageOffsetScale value="0.500000" />
      <diffuseTint value="0x00FFFFFF" />
      <steerWheelMult value="1.000000" />
      <HDTextureDist value="5.000000" />
      <lodDistances content="float_array">10
 25
 70
 500
</lodDistances>
      <identicalModelSpawnDistance value="20" />
      <maxNumOfSameColor value="10" />
      <defaultBodyHealth value="1000.000000" />
      <pretendOccupantsScale value="1.000000" />
      <visibleSpawnDistScale value="1.000000" />
      <trackerPathWidth value="2.000000" />
      <weaponForceMult value="1.000000" />
      <frequency value="1" />
      <swankness>SWANKNESS_5</swankness>
      <maxNum value="2" />
      <flags>FLAG_SPORTS FLAG_RICH_CAR FLAG_COUNT_AS_FACEBOOK_DRIVEN FLAG_EXTRAS_ALL FLAG_EXTRAS_STRONG</flags>
      <type>VEHICLE_TYPE_CAR</type>
      <plateType>VPT_BACK_PLATES</plateType>
      <vehicleClass>VC_SPORT_CLASSIC</vehicleClass>
      <wheelType>VWT_LOWRIDER</wheelType>
      <trailers />
      <additionalTrailers />
      <drivers />
      <extraIncludes />
      <doorsWithCollisionWhenClosed />
      <driveableDoors />
      <bumpersNeedToCollideWithMap value="false" />
      <needsRopeTexture value="false" />
      <requiredExtras />
      <rewards />
      <cinematicPartCamera>    
        <Item>WHEEL_FRONT_RIGHT_CAMERA
```

i question is how do i get the it to get the text between the first   tags so it give me all the text

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what language you are trying to do this in, and I'm not sure what you're hoping to do with the text after you have it, so it's hard to make a good answer. The easiest way to accomplish this task is to use an XML parser library, to enter into the  node, and dump the text of all its children.

I can highly recommend [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) as a Python XML parsing library, however something likely exists for the language of your choice.

**Update**: You've commented that your using C#, here is a tutorial on XML parsing with that language: [System.XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: I've edited the answer, in that case you can use something like C#'s System.XML (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)